# Is there any way to store qlearning table in external file?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I'm sorry the title might be misleading.

I'm currently working on a Q-Learning algorithm. I only can modify the Agent. And the runner doesn't implement episodes. 
Is there any way to make the agent store its learned q-values each time in a separate file, in order to reuse them the next time it runs.

Comment: Well yes, there are ways, but without code there is nothing to answer.

Comment: I've figured out a way to do this with a Json file. Thank you btw. @MatiasValdenegro

Comment: @BrainStorm this is a fairly common question I get in mentoring sessions, can you update the question to add some more details and then add an answer with your solution?